# Override field on complex joined MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have the below query, it's generated by a PHP function and it's gotten quite complex but it works fine so far.

What I want to do is override **one** field by a **second** field if a **third** field is equal to 1.

So I want **table2**.cpda_meta_val to actually equal **table3**.cpda_meta_val when **table4**.cpda_meta_val is equal to 1, so that I can then use the resulting value table2.cpda_meta_val in the WHERE / ORDER BY clauses.

I hope I've made sense so far.

Here is the original query:

```
SELECT
    mainTable.cpda_id 
FROM
    cp_data AS mainTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table0 
        ON table0.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table0.cpda_meta_key = '47248' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table1 
        ON table1.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table1.cpda_meta_key = '47241' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table2 
        ON table2.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table2.cpda_meta_key = '47242' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table3 
        ON table3.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table3.cpda_meta_key = '66838' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table4 
        ON table4.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table4.cpda_meta_key = '66843' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table5 
        ON table5.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table5.cpda_meta_key = '47252' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table6 
        ON table6.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table6.cpda_meta_key = '47255' 
WHERE
    mainTable.cpda_meta_id = 47236 
    AND mainTable.cpda_active = 1 
    AND mainTable.cpda_meta_key = 'set_element_stub' 
    AND table0.cpda_meta_val = 49297 
    AND table1.cpda_meta_val != 66116 
    AND (
        table5.cpda_meta_val = 497 
        OR table6.cpda_meta_val = 497
    ) 
ORDER BY
    table2.cpda_meta_val,
    mainTable.cpda_seq,
    mainTable.cpda_id
```

Here is my attempt at achieving the above, which doesn't work and retrieves no rows:

```
SELECT
    mainTable.cpda_id 
FROM
    cp_data AS mainTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table0 
        ON table0.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table0.cpda_meta_key = '47248' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table1 
        ON table1.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table1.cpda_meta_key = '47241' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table2 
        ON table2.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table2.cpda_meta_key = '47242' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table3 
        ON table3.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table3.cpda_meta_key = '66838' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table4 
        ON table4.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table4.cpda_meta_key = '66843' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table5 
        ON table5.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table5.cpda_meta_key = '47252' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table6 
        ON table6.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table6.cpda_meta_key = '47255'
CASE 
    WHEN table4.cpda_meta_val = 1 THEN table3.cpda_meta_val 
    ELSE table2.cpda_meta_val 
END as table2.cpda_meta_val 
WHERE
    mainTable.cpda_meta_id = 47236 
    AND mainTable.cpda_active = 1 
    AND mainTable.cpda_meta_key = 'set_element_stub' 
    AND table0.cpda_meta_val = 49297 
    AND table1.cpda_meta_val != 66116 
    AND (
        table5.cpda_meta_val = 497 
        OR table6.cpda_meta_val = 497
    ) 
ORDER BY
    table2.cpda_meta_val,
    mainTable.cpda_seq,
    mainTable.cpda_id
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great! Thanks!

**EDIT - For those searching, I used Gordon's answer below to make the following query that now works:**

```
SELECT
    mainTable.cpda_id,
    (CASE 
        WHEN table4.cpda_meta_val = 1 THEN table3.cpda_meta_val 
        ELSE table2.cpda_meta_val 
    END) as override_val_0 
FROM
    cp_data AS mainTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table0 
        ON table0.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table0.cpda_meta_key = '47248' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table1 
        ON table1.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table1.cpda_meta_key = '47241' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table2 
        ON table2.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table2.cpda_meta_key = '47242' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table3 
        ON table3.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table3.cpda_meta_key = '66838' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table4 
        ON table4.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table4.cpda_meta_key = '66843' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table5 
        ON table5.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table5.cpda_meta_key = '47252' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cp_data AS table6 
        ON table6.cpda_meta_id = mainTable.cpda_id 
        AND table6.cpda_meta_key = '47255' 
WHERE
    mainTable.cpda_meta_id = 47236 
    AND mainTable.cpda_active = 1 
    AND mainTable.cpda_meta_key = 'set_element_stub' 
    AND table0.cpda_meta_val = 49297 
    AND table1.cpda_meta_val != 66116 
    AND (
        table5.cpda_meta_val = 497 
        OR table6.cpda_meta_val = 497
    ) 
ORDER BY
    override_val_0,
    mainTable.cpda_seq,
    mainTable.cpda_id
```

Comment: I think first thing - is to wrap complex and hard to understand joins into VIEWs with understandable names and meaning where some overrides could be applyed. Then rewrite query using only required fields and minimum changes on them.

Comment: I think VIEWs would be overkill for this seeing as the query is generated with code and is largely automated. I'm now using the answer below as another feather to the generator's bow so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case` statement belongs in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT mainTable.cpda_id,
       (CASE WHEN table4.cpda_meta_val = 1 THEN table3.cpda_meta_val
             ELSE table2.cpda_meta_val 
        END) as cpda_meta_val
```

You can put this expression directly in the `order by` as well (which seems to be the only place you use `table2_cpda_meta_val`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN table4.cpda_meta_val = 1 THEN table3.cpda_meta_val
                 ELSE table2.cpda_meta_val 
          END),
         mainTable.cpda_seq,
         mainTable.cpda_id
```

Comment: Ah of course!! Thanks Gordon have a great Friday XD